# Is "class" is predefined class in Java?

Tags: java, class

Can we say that `java.lang.Class` is predefined class in Java?

I am really confused on this.. I am new to Java so I am not sure. So please let me know the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class` is a class where as `class` is a keyword.

- Type [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

  > Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a
  >   running Java application.
- Keyword`class` ([JLS Chapter 8 ff.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html))

  > Class declarations define new reference types and describe how they are implemented 
  >   [...]
  >   A class declaration specifies a new named reference type.

Answer (score 0):

**Class** `java.lang.Class`. Class objects contain runtime representations of classes. Every object in the system is an instance of some Class, and for each Class there is one of these descriptor objects.
A Class descriptor is not modifiable at runtime

**Declaration**

```
public final class Class<T> extends Object
implements Serializable, GenericDeclaration, Type, AnnotatedElement
```